# How to properly escape consecutive two-digit point-style (pch) values when drawing legends in R

Tags: r, graph, legend

I'm trying to draw a legend in R that has three different point styles, all with two-digit pch values. I've escpated each value with a backslash, but R isn't reading that correctly and I can't figure out the correct syntax. Below is a toy example, along with the output graph. This syntax works fine with single-digit pch values. What's the secret for properly escaping two-digit pch values?

```
y1 = 1:10
y2 = rep(5,10)
y3 = seq(3.5,4.4,.1)
x = 1:10
plot(x,y1, pch=19, lty=1, type="b", ylab="")
lines(x,y2, pch=15, lty=2, type="b", col="red")
lines(x,y3, pch=17, lty=3, type="b", col="blue")
legend(1,10, 
   c("Y1","Y2","Y3"), 
   lty=c(1,2,3), 
   pch=c("\19\15\17"), 
   col=c("black","red","blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why didn't you just do `pch=c(19,15,17)`?

Comment: Doh! I'm obviously the one who's missing something. This is my first R legend and for some reason the help file had me thinking of character strings, rather than the obvious, R-like method. Hence, my trip down the rabbit-hole of escape characters. The help file says: "the plotting symbols appearing in the legend, either as vector of 1-character strings, or one (multi character) string. Must be specified for symbol drawing." Once the character string worked for single-digit pch values, I just kept banging my head against that method instead stepping back and thinking in a more R-like fashion.

Comment: Yeah, that happens sometimes. Go ahead and put that in an answer yourself if you like, so this can be marked as accepted.

Comment: @joran even though your method is clearly the best way, I'd still like to understand a bit better how escaping works. In this case, `pch="\1\5\7"`, for example, gives the point types you'd expect, but `pch="\19\15\17"` doesn't. Is there a way to correctly escape two-digit strings so that R understands them correctly? This seems like the kind of knowledge that might come in handy some day in the right context.

Comment: I don't think the intent was for there to be any character escaping features here. Try just `pch = "abc"`. It's parsing the string one character at a time, that's all. When you start escaping things, depending on the character encodings you'll get different stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joran said in his comment, just do `pch=c(19,15,17)`.